# Last Item in List<Object> is repeated in a specific textview of RecyclerView item

Tags: android, json, dataset, android-recyclerview

I am using Object class( `public static List<Restaurant> res;`) to set data that I am getting json data from server.  The flow of the app is as follow.

**Step 1:  (MainActivity.class)**

Getting data from server

**Step 2:**

Set all the Json data into `List<Object>` class. And declared `List<Object>` as a **public static in MainActivity**

**Step 3:**

Here I need to populate `List<Object>` class values into the Recyclerview.Due to declared as public static, I called this directly while setting in adapter in a fragment which has a MainActivity as a parent.

```
  adapter = new CardAdapter(MainActivity.res, context);
  recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
  adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

**But the issue is that while populating RecyclerView,I am getting only the last Item is repeated upto the** `List<Restaurant>` **size.**

**MainActivity (AsyncTask Method):**

```
 private class TabNameSync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
        String BASE_URL = Config.DATA_URL;
        ProgressDialog nDialog;
        HashMap<String, String> hashMapPost = new HashMap<>();

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            nDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            nDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            nDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
            nDialog.setCancelable(true);
            nDialog.show();
        }

        @Override

        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

            HttpURLConnection con = null;
            InputStream is = null;

            StringBuffer buffer;
            String bufferVariable = null;

            hashMapPost.put("tag", "onload");
            hashMapPost.put("lat", "18.71851808");
            hashMapPost.put("log", "97.74131474");

            try {
                con = (HttpURLConnection) (new URL(BASE_URL)).openConnection();
                con.setDoInput(true);
                con.setDoOutput(true);
                con.setRequestMethod("POST");
                con.connect();
                OutputStream os = con.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                        new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
                writer.write(commonUtil.getPostDataString(hashMapPost));

                writer.flush();
                writer.close();
                os.close();

                buffer = new StringBuffer();
                int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
                if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                    is = con.getInputStream();
                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
                    String line;
                    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
                        buffer.append(line).append("\r\n");
                    is.close();
                }
                con.disconnect();
                bufferVariable = buffer.toString();
                return buffer.toString();
            } catch (Throwable t) {
                t.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    if (is != null) {
                        is.close();
                    }
                } catch (Throwable t) {
                }
                try {
                    if (con != null) {
                        con.disconnect();
                    }
                } catch (Throwable t) {
                }
                if (!bufferVariable.equalsIgnoreCase(" ")) {
                    try {

                        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(bufferVariable);
                        int jsonLength = jArray.length();

                        for (int j = 0; j < jArray.length(); j++) {

                            Restaurant_Beam item;
                            JSONObject jsonObj = jArray.getJSONObject(j);
                            item = new Restaurant_Beam();
                            item.setIG_LIKECOUNT(jsonObj.getInt(Config.LIKE));
                            item.setIG_DELIVERY(jsonObj.getInt(Config.DELIVERYTIME));
                            item.setIG_PRODUCTID(jsonObj.getString(Config.PRODUCTID));
                            item.setIG_SALES_PRICE(jsonObj.getString(Config.SALESPRICE));
                            item.setIG_VOUCHER_ID(jsonObj.getString(Config.VOUCHERID));
                            item.setIG_VOUCHEROFFER(jsonObj.getString(Config.VOUCHEROFFER));
                            item.setIG_CATEGORY_ID(jsonObj.getString(Config.CATEID));
                            item.setIG_IMAGEURL(jsonObj.getString(Config.IMGID));
                            item.setIG_PRODUCTNAME(jsonObj.getString(Config.PRODUCTNAME));
                            item.setIG_CATEGORYNAME(jsonObj.getString(Config.CATENAME));

                            Restaurant.add(item);

                            listSuperHeroes = Restaurant;

                            strTabName = jsonObj.getString("Cate Name");
                            String strProductID = jsonObj.getString("Pro_Id");
                            String strProductName = jsonObj.getString("Product_Name");
                            String strSalesPrice = jsonObj.getString("Sales Price");
                            String strVoucherId = jsonObj.getString("Voucher Id");
                            String strVoucherOffer = jsonObj.getString("voucher Offer");
                            String strCatId = jsonObj.getString("Cat Id");
                            String strImage = jsonObj.getString("Image");
                            String strLikes = jsonObj.getString("likes");
                            String strDeliveryTime = jsonObj.getString("deliverytime");
                            strDbName = jsonObj.getString("dbname");


                            tabName.add(strTabName);

                            DbName.add(strDbName);

                            if (jsonLength == jArray.length()) {
                                JSONObject jsonObj2 = jArray.getJSONObject(jsonLength - 1);
                                Config.IMAGE_URL = jsonObj2.getString("url");
                            }
                        }


                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            final TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
            tabLayout.setTabMode(TabLayout.MODE_SCROLLABLE);

            values = new ArrayList<String>();
            values = tabName;
            HashSet<String> hashSet = new HashSet<String>();
            hashSet.addAll(values);
            values.clear();
            values.addAll(hashSet);

            nDialog.dismiss();

            //    setTime_ToSlide();
            viewPager.setAdapter(new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));
            tabLayout.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
                }
            });
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
            editor.putString("FIRST_TAB", values.get(1));
            editor.putString("SECOND_TAB", values.get(0));
            editor.putString("THIRD_TAB", values.get(2));
            editor.commit();

        }
    }
```

[image]

***Here only the RED rounderd data is repeated and the other data are relevant to the correct data.***

I have posted my code too.Please check it.

Comment: post your adapter code

Comment: is your list populated correctly?

Comment: Yeah posted the code

Comment: Where do you initialize you array `public static List<Restaurant> res;` ?

Comment: Globally in MainActivity class.

Comment: I can't see the problem... Please post your whole `MainActivity`.

Answer (score 1):

send list object with CardAdapter Constructor

```
new CardAdapter(MainActivity.res, context, List<object> abc);
```

then use it.

Comment: MainActivity.res is the List<Object> @Vinay

Comment: List<Restaurant> res  --> Stores everything in it and I passed it to the Adapter

Comment: res is static , then u no need to paas , u can directly use it. in CardAdapter.

Answer (score 1):

Your code has a "referencing" problem. Move `Restaurant item= new Restaurant();` inside the loop. Like this:

```
public static List<Restaurant> res;
     try {
                            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(bufferVariable);
                            int jsonLength = jArray.length();
                            for (int j = 0; j < jArray.length(); j++) {
                                JSONObject jsonObj = jArray.getJSONObject(j);

                                strTabName = jsonObj.getString("Cate Name");
                                Restaurant item= new Restaurant();

                                item.setIG_LIKECOUNT(jsonObj.getInt(Config.LIKE));
                                item.setIG_DELIVERY(jsonObj.getInt(Config.DELIVERYTIME));
                                item.setIG_PRODUCTID(jsonObj.getString(Config.PRODUCTID));
                                item.setIG_PRODUCTNAME(jsonObj.getString(Config.PRODUCTNAME));
                                item.setIG_SALES_PRICE(jsonObj.getString(Config.SALESPRICE));
                                item.setIG_VOUCHER_ID(jsonObj.getString(Config.VOUCHERID));
                                item.setIG_VOUCHEROFFER(jsonObj.getString(Config.VOUCHEROFFER));
                                item.setIG_CATEGORY_ID(jsonObj.getString(Config.CATEID));
                                item.setIG_CATEGORYNAME(jsonObj.getString(Config.CATENAME));
                                item.setIG_IMAGEURL(jsonObj.getString(Config.IMGID));

                                res.add(item);

                                if (jsonLength == jArray.length()) {
                                    JSONObject jsonObj2 = jArray.getJSONObject(jsonLength - 1);
                                    Config.IMAGE_URL = jsonObj2.getString("url");
                                }
                            }
```

Comment: I posted code which populate List<Object>.Can you please check?

Comment: Updated my answer, see it.

Comment: Sorry...Still it is repeated as previous.

Comment: It should not, unless you are getting repetitive data from the server. Do a clean build and run again.

Comment: I followed your last instructions too.But still it is same. I dont know at where I did mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed bug by myself. What I have changed is that I had set every variable(*Product Name,CategoryName*) as public static String in `List<Object>` class.

After removing **static** I got the exact result.My **RecyclerView** is adapted as perfect.Like the following

Instead of

```
public static String ProductName;
```

use this

```
public String ProductName;
```